# Conditions such that $T(t)x \in D(A)$ for $C_0$-Semigroup

Tags: semigroup-of-operators

Consider a $C_0$-Semigroup $(T(t))_{t \ge 0}$ on the Banachspace $X$. Are there any conditions on $x \in X$ or the semigroup such that for any $t > 0$ it holds $T(t)x \in D(A)$? Here $(A,D(A))$ denotes the Generator with its domain $D(A)$.

Comment: Let me ask a silly question. Consider the heat semigroup $e^{t\Delta}$ on $L^2(\mathbb R)$. Does it satisfy this property? (If not, there's little hope in general, IMHO)

Comment: Indeed, it was silly, of course $e^{t\Delta}$ does satisfy the property. I made a bit of bibliographical research, see answer below.

Comment: Tahnk you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semigroups which satisfy the property you mention are called *immediately differentiable* (see [Engel-Nagel's book](https://books.google.es/books?id=q0YMCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PR1&pg=PA109#v=onepage&q&f=false), Section 4.b, "Differentiable semigroups"). Corollary 4.15 provides a characterization in terms of a spectral property of the generator.

Analytic semigroups, which are holomorphic in the time variable on a sector in the complex plane, are immediately differentiable semigroups ([see also this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2083018/analytic-semigroups-and-norm-continuous-semigroups?rq=1#comment4281320_2083018) ). See Section 4.a of the aforementioned book.